# Regular sequence of elements of degree 1 for a homogeneous Cohen-Macaulay ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Assume that a positively graded ring R is generated in degree 1. Is it true that, if R is Cohen-Macaulay, then there exists a regular sequence **x** of elements of degree 1 so that R/**x** is zero dimensional?

I tend to believe that it holds, but could not find a reference. Maybe some extra condition should be imposed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to assume also that the residue field is infinite.  Then a minimal reduction of the irrelevant ideal will be a system of parameters, each linear, and will be a maximal regular sequence.

Comment: And over a finite field $k$, consider the union $V$ of all hyperplans of $\mathbb P^n_k$ and let $R$ be the obvious corresponding homogeneous algebra. Then $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay, but all elements of degree 1 are zero divisors. 